# import controller from another directory

Tags: controller, sails.js

I would like to import a controller from  `/frontoffice`  directory. But sails auto import only loads files in `/api/controllers`.

Is there a way to tell sails where to look for controllers?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Sails v0.10.x, you can set the `paths.controllers` property in your `.sailsrc` file, which will override all other config:

```
{
    "paths": {
        "controllers": "/absolute/path/to/frontoffice"
    }
}
```

In v0.9x, the only way to override this config would be to set it directly in `app.js`, using `lodash` to merge in the command line options:

```
var _ = require('sails/node_modules/lodash');
var cmdLine = require('optimist').argv;
var args = {paths: {controllers: "/absolute/path/to/frontoffice"}};
var opts = _.extend(args, cmdLine);
require('sails').lift(opts);
```

Then lift with `node app.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Try out

```
    var frontoffice = require('./frontoffice.js');
```